# What's the differences between these two ways of cloning a sender for a Rust channel?

Tags: rust, duplicates, clone, channel

In the Rust official book 16-11, it duplicates a channel sender by

```
let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
let tx1 = mpsc::Sender::clone(&tx);
```

But I tried

```
let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
let tx1 = tx.clone();
```

which also works. What's the differences between them? If they are essentially the same, why creating a separate method considering we already have the general `clone()` method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function signature for `clone` looks like this. Note that it takes `&self` as a parameter:

```rust
fn clone(&self) -> Sender<T>;
```

You can either invoke the function by explicitly passing `&self`:

```rust
mpsc::Sender::clone(&tx);
```

Or by using a [method call expression](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html):

```rust
tx.clone();
```

Method call expressions are just syntactic sugar, although the compiler does has to perform a more complex lookup process to generate the correct reference type for `self`.

Note that this works with any other associated method that takes `self`:

```rust
pub struct Bar {}

impl Bar {
    fn bla(&self) {}
}

fn main() {
    let bar = Bar {};
    
    // these are equivalent
    bar.bla();
    Bar::bla(&bar)
}
```